# update-rc.d-native-0.8-r0 do_unpack: Bitbake Fetcher Error: UnpackError on yocto project

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

My Yocto project version

"4.0.15"

encounter error while building

```
ERROR: update-rc.d-native-0.8-r0 do_unpack: Bitbake Fetcher Error: UnpackError('No up to date source found: clone directory not available or not up to date: /build/downloads/git2/git.yoctoproject.org.update-rc.d; shallow clone not enabled', 'git://git.yoctoproject.org/update-rc.d;branch=master')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/update-rc.d-native/0.8-r0/temp/log.do_unpack.11298
```

\src\poky\meta\recipes-core\update-rc.d\update-rc.d_0.8.bb

```
SUMMARY = "manage symlinks in /etc/rcN.d"
HOMEPAGE = "http://github.com/philb/update-rc.d/"
DESCRIPTION = "update-rc.d is a utility that allows the management of symlinks to the initscripts in the /etc/rcN.d directory structure."
SECTION = "base"

LICENSE = "GPL-2.0-or-later"


SRC_URI = "git://git.yoctoproject.org/update-rc.d;branch=master"
SRCREV = "8636cf478d426b568c1be11dbd9346f67e03adac"

UPSTREAM_CHECK_COMMITS = "1"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit allarch

do_compile() {
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${sbindir}
    install -m 0755 ${S}/update-rc.d ${D}${sbindir}/update-rc.d
}

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

I do check my bblayers.conf

```
  /aiot-yocto/src/poky/meta \
  /aiot-yocto/src/poky/meta-poky \
  /aiot-yocto/src/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
```

it seems like the both the .bb file and  bblayers.conf is correctly set
.Anyone know why Error happened?

Comment: somehow i just  remove entire layer and rebuild it does not show any error again not sure why does this error happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow i just remove entire layer and rebuild it does not show any error again not sure why does this error happened